# Will loot you find on the Astral Plane while using the Astral Projection spell remain in your possession when the spell ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, planes, astral

While under the effect of the [*astral projection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection) spell, you have an astral body which has the following rules:

> Your astral body resembles your mortal form in almost every way, replicating your game statistics and possessions.

I don't think that you keep stuff if you pick it normally because of the following line (but please correct me if I'm wrong):

> Any damage or other effects that apply to it have no effect on your physical body, nor do they persist when you return to it.

It doesn't specifically say that you cannot pick up loot and take it with you, but it differentiates the astral form from the physical form in a way that they are in no way connected (except the cord).

But, my possessions are being replicated, including my *bag of holding*. If I pick something up in the Astral Plane and put it into my *bag of holding*, will it remain in there when I return to my physical body?

Comment: It might be useful to put the corollary in there, since it is pretty close to the same answer. If a possession is lost or destroyed on your astral body, is it OK when you return?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No, you can't take things back from the Astral Plane, because you don't physically go there; your consciousness does.

The description of the [Astral Plane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-a-multiverse#AstralPlane) in the DMG states (p. 46; emphasis mine):

> The Astral Plane is the realm of thought and dream, where visitors
> travel **as disembodied souls** to reach the Outer Planes.
>
> [...]
>
> Traveling through the Astral Plane by means of the *astral projection*
> spell involves projecting **one's consciousness** there, [...]

You only have gear with you as your consciousness manifests it, so you can "use" it on the Astral Plane, but your real body and all your real possessions are back on the Prime Material Plane. You can no more take gear back with you than you can take things back from a dream.

Comment: How does this answer square with "If you enter a new plane... your body and possessions are transported along the silver cord, allowing you to re-enter your body as you enter the new plane"?  When you pop out of a color pool, you physically appear with all your actually real stuff in the new plane. Presumably any objects your astral body grabbed along the way will similarly appear since you just pushed it through the same portal you came through.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, it will

The description of the [*astral projection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection) spell says:

> If you enter a new plane or return to the plane you were on when
> casting this spell, your body and possessions are transported along
> the silver cord, allowing you to re-enter your body as you enter the
> new plane.
>
> [...]
>
> When the spell ends, the affected creature returns to its physical
> body, and it awakens.

This suggests that things acquired by the astral body will travel with that astral body back to your real body.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you put the loot into your Bag of Holding, yes. Otherwise, no.

When you cast the spell, it replicates your equipment, including your magic items. This would include your Bag of Holding, which acts as a portal to an extradimensional space; it wouldn't replicate the extradimensional space, however, just the bag's ability to connect to it. As a result, you'd have both your astral Bag of Holding and your material Bag of Holding connecting to the same extradimensional space.

When the spell ends and your projection returns to your real body, all effects affecting it end, including any loot you've acquired. As a result, unless the loot has been placed into the Bag of Holding and transferred to the extradimensional space it connects to, you will lose the loot you've acquired.