# Can someone using "Astral Projection" gather materials scattered through the Astral Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, astral

Let's say that a [***bag of holding***](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4581-bag-of-holding/) holding valuable items (I don't think it matters what but tell me if it does) was split in two, and

> its contents [were] scattered in the Astral Plane.

In order to retrieve these items, can the party use *[astral projection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection/)*  to gather the items? The spell mentions that the projection has your

> game statistics and possessions

but it doesn't mention anything about coming back. The party knows where  the items are in the Astral Plane, the only problem is getting them.

If the party can't use *astral projection* to get the items, how can they get them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### They go on a quest

You can physically travel to the Astral with *Plane Shift* (or *Gate*, but *Plane Shift* is lower level and on more spell lists). If you know *exactly* where the item is, *Plane Shift* can get you close (though "close" might still mean days of travel or more, if the DM is mean), and *Gate* could drop you next to it.

But to be clear, when a *Bag of Holding* ruptures, the contents are not usually in a known location. "Scattered in the Astral Plane" is roughly equivalent to (if not more hopeless than) "scattered across the Earth". There's no specific place you'll find any given item. In most games, you'd just consider them lost. If they're *really* important, you *Plane Shift*/*Gate* after them (or find a portal to the Astral or whatever) and go looking for them, in the same way people on Earth might quest after the Holy Grail. Feel free to use magic, divine contacts, demonic servants, beat a githyanki to reveal where a collected item was hoarded, whatever, but you're looking for a needle in a *very* large haystack. Good luck!

---

Side-note: I ignored *Astral Projection* in the above, because:

1. It's [arguable whether it provides *any* means of taking items collected by your astral self back to your real body at all](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93491/28941) (and if it does, you still have to find a portal to some other plane to do it, and you end up whereever that portal goes, not where you started); ending the spell normally definitely doesn't work (your spirit just snaps back to your body), and finding a portal to another plane has wording that favors an interpretation where you'd only have your original equipment, not whatever your astral self might have collected en route (a generous DM might have the stuff you collected spill through the portal as your spirit transitions through the portal and into the newly appearing original body and possessions).
2. It's higher level and on fewer spell lists than *Plane Shift*, and unlike either *Gate* or *Plane Shift*, provides no means of appearing near any given place in the Astral.

So even if you knew *exactly* where your items were, *and* you have a DM that allows collected items to go through a portal with you, you'd have to travel an arbitrary distance from where you appear to find the items, then travel to find a portal (hopefully to a plane you want to be on), where the same level *Gate* could have you there and back in moments, and *Plane Shift* would at least get you close and only require resting to cast it again to return.

If you really want to, *Astral Projection* is a potential option, it just introduces more complications when you've actually found the items. People tend to think of *Astral Projection* first, because it has "Astral" right in the name, but the Astral is just another plane, so you can reach it with [any technique that allows you to plane hop](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104036/28941), and it's usually easier than *Astral Projection* (which is mostly useful for the "you're pseudo-invulnerable to anything that can't cut a silver cord" and "you can always go back where you started easily" effects, but it's not anything special in terms of planar access).

Comment: Note that the question includes the sentence: "The party knows where the items are in the Astral Plane, the only problem is getting them." Otherwise, excellent answer.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin: Frankly, I'm skeptical they'd know where the items are, but heck, if they really do, *Plane Shift* is the answer.

Comment: Well, there are some magical ways of finding the item and even some things that you always know the location of if you are in the same plane as them.

Comment: @TurtleTail: I won't say it's impossible, but AFAICT, [5E has no long distance object locating magic](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/9hvlup/is_there_a_spell_that_can_locate_an_object_over/); the obvious candidate spell, *Locate Object*, is limited to 1000'. I'm sure there are some special cases, but they'd be extremely rare exceptions (the odds of *multiple* such valuable items *all* being locatable over the infinite expanse of the Astral, so you could track down each wherever it scattered to, seem fairly low).

Comment: The sole advantage they've got is that, assuming Astral travel functions similarly in 5E as it does in 2E (5E DMG mentions combat movement without describing non-combat travel), you can reach any point in the infinite Astral essentially by trying to travel there long enough. If I recall the 2E rules correctly, getting from any point A to any known point B in the Astral takes a random amount of time, but maxes out in single digit days, so it's not like needing to travel from Kara-Tur to Maztica (or worse, Krynn), where, barring teleportation magic, you'll be traveling for months, if not years.

Comment: The thing in question was a magical artifact that gives off a particular magical signal; it's how they found it in the first place, on a different plane, so that's how they know how it is.

Comment: @Firedestroyer: Okay, so it's just one item they're concerned with, and it's easy to locate. In that case, if they can track that signal from another plane and know *exactly* where it's coming from on the Astral, *Gate* can make pickup a breeze. If they have to be on the Astral first to locate it, then they can just *Plane Shift*, go a-questing, and *Plane Shift* back when they're done (or locate an acceptable color pool instead if they can't *Plane Shift* for whatever reason). Travel movement in the Astral isn't well specified in 5E, but in prior editions you could get anywhere in a few days.

Comment: If you have access to *astral projection*, using it to collect everything could be a good idea even if you can’t bring things back: if nothing else, you could collect everything in one convenient place within the Astral while *projecting*, and use another means to go in, scoop everything up, and get out. Limits how long you have to be physically present and vulnerable.

Comment: @KRyan: Sure. That said, these are adventurers we're talking about. Anywhere but the Astral they'd be equally vulnerable in the flesh anyway. And the Astral isn't even that dangerous (it's pretty empty). In some ways the silver cord makes you *more* vulnerable, not less; the two biggest threats on the Astral (githyanki and astral dreadnoughts) can both sever silver cords (not all githyanki at least), making their crits insta-death for projected travelers (in older editions, astral dreadnoughts would *only* attack you if you were astrally projecting, they ignored anyone there in the flesh).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Long distance object locating is possible via spells that can answer generic questions, like Divination. You may not get as clear and direct an answer as you'd like but cryptic clues to the location of an important item are just par for the course.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: Sure, I mentioned that as a possibility in the answer ("Feel free to *use magic, divine contacts*, demonic servants, beat a githyanki to reveal where a collected item was hoarded...", where *Divination* is both the highlighted things). But as you note, you're generally not expecting a clear answer (certainly nothing clear enough for you to know where to *Gate* precisely enough to be in, grab the item, and out in the one minute duration of *Gate*), so you're on a quest, using whatever guidance you have available. This isn't just "get to the Astral and your problem is solved".

Answer (score 7):

### What happens on the Astral Plane, stays on the Astral Plane

Towards the middle of the spell it states:

> Your astral form is a **separate incarnation**. Any damage or other effects that apply to it have no effect on your physical body, nor do they persist when you return to it.

Your projection is not you. It is, literally, a projection.

Picture it like being in a virtual reality simulator. If you got stabbed in the simulator, you are not stabbed in your corporeal form. Should you actually find the thing(s) you are looking for, you can put it in your Astral pocket. But when the spell ends, you don't get to keep what's in your Astral pocket. Just like you don't bring back damage you took to your projection.

### But...what about my stuff?

Part way through the spell it states:

> Your astral form can freely travel through the Astral Plane and can pass through portals there leading to any other plane. If you enter a new plane or return to the plane you were on when casting this spell, **your body and possessions are transported along the silver cord**, allowing you to re-enter your body as you enter the new plane.

So that means that the stuff you grab becomes part of your possessions and appear on the other side, right?

Not so fast.

Earlier in the spell it mentions, "Your astral body **resembles** your mortal form in almost every way, **replicating** your game statistics and possessions." So the possessions you bring to the plane are the ones you started with. Then, when you walk through a portal (whether to a new plane or back to where you started), your body, and the possession on your PHYSICAL body, are teleported "along the silver cord" to the destination. If that later phrase didn't say possessions there would be the possibility of you and your possessions being projected, but when you go through a portal, only your body appears. Welcome to the Plane of Fire, naked.

So to actually bring something back, you'll need a different spell.

### Using Gate or Plane Shift will bring your bodies to the Astral Plane

So instead of projecting, you need to actually **go** to the plane and get back your items. And I'm quite impressed that you found it/them; the Astral Plane is big. Really big. You just won't believe how vastly hugely mind-bogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist, but that's just peanuts to a whole Plane.

Comment: This answer seems to ignore an important fact: "If you enter a new plane... your body and possessions are transported along the silver cord, allowing you to re-enter your body as you enter the new plane."  If you astrally project, find some of your stuff, then go through a color pool to, say, the plane of Air, you'd appear in the plane of air in your real body, with all your real stuff, and presumably anything you picked up in the Astral plane.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, you're right. I added something to the comment of a different answer, but it never made it to mine. I'll merge that in shortly. But I will say, "presumably" is not "an important fact". It's just a detail I haven't clarified.

Comment: @MivaScott I finally understood what you meant (took me a long time, I know...). The body that is referred to as being transported with its possessions is not your astral form, it is the *original* body, and hence the original bodies possessions. I deleted my answer for now and upvoted yours. I think that has the interesting aspect that you can generate unlimited uses of consumable items in the astral plane, because when you use them there, the original items are not destroyed. That is  likely somehow exploitable... but maybe that is just par for the course on a level 9 spell. Thanks!

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin, I appreciate that. When I moved my comment from your post to my answer, I had more space to clarify details. As for exploiting, remember that any effects from something on the Astral Projection do not transfer back to the host body. So you could spend a month reading a Tome of Understanding in the Astral Plane, and that would boost the wisdom of your projection, but it would not boost the wisdom of the host body. So I don't think there is a lot of exploits available.

Comment: @MivaScott The fact is that you appear materially when you astrally project and enter another plane. The presumption is that any loot you collected will come with you, though it's hard to see how that would *not* be the case.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, by that logic, I could be run through by a sword while projecting and then exit to another plane. When I arrive, I would not have a wound, because "[a]ny damage or other effects that apply to it have no effect on your physical body, nor do they persist when you return to it." But I could still keep the sword that's piercing my body. Why would wounds and effect sustained on the plane not persist but grabbing something and putting it in your pocket does? It's not a matter of proximity as wounds are are as close to your body and something can be.

Comment: @MivaScott So if my astral self has an object in hand, and passes through a color pool with the object, where did the object go?  Are you going to really rule that it didn't go through the portal even though I watched it do exactly that?  Give me a break.  You're taking the bizarre case of what is effectively a transporter accident and using that as the basis of a ruling instead of the obvious basic case?  You lose your wounds because the wounds were on an astral duplicate of you which is instantaneously replaced by the real you. That doesn't suggest that things in your hands suddenly vanish.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym, If that object in hand isn't something to entered the Astral Plane with, then it just doesn't show up once you pass through the portal. It stays on the Astral Plane. Why? Because you're not really IN the Astral Plane, just a projection is. Honestly, VR is the best way to think about this. It's a replica of you, in a difference space. You can do things there, but none of it transfers back to the host you. If you pick up a rock in VR, you don't suddenly gain a rock in your host/physical hand.

Comment: Yeah but when I take off my VR helmet, I can't teleport to Mars.  Astral Projection can do that.  "You can't *really* interact with things while astral projected" is .... certainly a position to take.